# How can I implement a revealing light beam?

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders, lighting

In SEARCHLIGHT, you control a ray of light that illuminates incoming enemies that are otherwise invisible in the night sky. Here is an illustration:

[image: Illustration]

How would I go about doing this, preferably in Unity? I imagine this is less about lighting and more about shaders, but I'm not sure on details. The fact that I know very little about coding shaders makes it worse.

If it *is* about shaders, what are the specifics? Is there a stretched quad that moves with said shader applied to it, or perhaps is using the [Line Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) a better option?

As a beginner, may I try to achieve a similar effect, or should I leave it for when I'm better?

(P.S.: The game was made in Unity. [Here](https://itch.io/jam/brackeys/rate/299485) is its itch.io page.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to implement an effect like this is with the [stencil buffer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html).

This is an extra few bits the renderer keeps around for every pixel in a render target, that you can use for scratch notes about what you've drawn there or are allowed to draw later.

You can create a new shader using one of Unity's built-in templates, and add some stencil operations to the top of the `SubShader` or `Pass` section:

```
Stencil {
    Ref 1
    Comp always
    Pass replace
}
```

This says "write a 1 into the stencil buffer, no matter what was there before" - put this on the shader/material that you use to render your light beam quad, and it will mark all the on-screen pixels it's touched.

Then, for objects that should only show up inside the light beam, use:

```
Stencil {
    Ref 1
    Comp equal
}
```

This checks to see if the magic number 1 got written into this pixel previously (ie. is this pixel illuminated by the light beam?) - if not, the shader aborts rendering this pixel of the object, neatly clipping it to just the illuminated region of your screen.

Make sure your objects that read the stencil information [render later in the queues](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html) than the objects that write it, so the information is ready for them when they look for it.